# Assuming a bullish stock, any advantage in using LT RSUs to fund exercise cost of ISOs?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, employee-stock-options, rsu

#### Example

Present Information:

- Example Dummy Stock: GGG | Stock Price @ `$10`
- Super bullish and so assume the value of the stock price will go up.
- ISOs: `10,000` with SP @ `$5.00` (All vested, just not exercised)

  - That would mean in order to get the `10,000` stocks, one would need `$50,000`.
- RSUs: `1,000` that are vested + Long Term (Held for >12 months)

Future Information:

- Stock Price `$50`

Scenarios:

(For full conversion to $$$ both ISOs and RSUs)

(Will not consider the case of holding onto the exercised ISOs due to messy AMT dynamic.)

##### 1:)

- ISOs (`10,000`):

  - Sell to Cover (`-1,000` * `$50` = `-$50,000`)
  - -> Sell Remaining (`9,000` * `$50` = `$450,000`)
- RSUs (`1,000`):

  - Sell Long Termed (`1,000` * `$50` = `$50,000`)
- Effective Proceeds: `$500,000!`

##### 2:)

- RSUs (`1,000`):

  - Sell Long Termed (`1,000` * `$50` = `$50,000`)
- ISOs (`10,000`):

  - Exercise with RSU proceeds (`-1,000` * `$50` = `-$50,000`)
  - -> Sell Exercised ISOs (`10,000` * `$50` = `$500,000`)
- Effective Proceeds: `$500,000!`

Both scenarios have the same *effective* proceeds. The kicker as most know is the tax bill that needs to be paid by next April.

So are there any advantages in scenario `2` due to the fact that LT RSUs were used to exercise? My DIY finance gut tells me yes, but perhaps there is no difference and the pros/cons cancel each other out in the end.

-**Edit**

The scenario is in the USA.

Comment: What country's taxes are you asking about?

Comment: Sorry. I should have stated. I'll edit my original post with that information. But USA for the taxes.